# How to replace DomRepeatModel.item?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have the following code snippet that listen on button click event for item on a list created by dom-repeat (Polymer 1.0.0-rc.17). According to polymer.dart change.log, `DomRepeatModel.item is now deprecated, although it will properly use the as attribute for now. The [] operator has been added in its place`. Anyone knows how to apply it to the code to get the same result?

```
@reflectable
handlePurchase(event, [_]) {
    print('Purchase item');
    var model = new DomRepeatModel.fromEvent(event);
    ShopItem item = model.item;

    print(item.name);
    print(item.price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, it is simply model['item'].